# print selected value from re.split

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to get values from a string like:

```
   4 F= -0.15857709E+03 E0= -0.15857306E+03  d E =-0.612557E+01  mag=   111.0022
```

To print the numbers only, eg, like:

```
4 -0.15857709E+03 -0.15857306E+03 -0.612557E+01 111.0022
```

I am doing:

```
indices = [1, 4, 7, 11, 14]
slist = re.split(" +|=|\n", line)# for i in indices)
qlist =[slist[i] for i in indices]
print(*qlist)
```

Am I required to do all that? (I mean, I am creating 2 list just to print the numbers).

Is there a better way of doing this(directly from re.split, may be)?

I was trying:

```
        print(re.split(" +|=|\n", line)[i] for i in indices)
```

which is yielding error:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f90bfbb80d8>

**NB** This will created a 2-d list like:

```
1 -0.15245151E+03 -0.15244677E+03 -0.152452E+03 104.3267
2 -0.15552770E+03 -0.15552383E+03 -0.307619E+01 108.0036
3 -0.15807566E+03 -0.15807147E+03 -0.562415E+01 111.0046
4 -0.15857709E+03 -0.15857306E+03 -0.612557E+01 111.0022
```

Comment: Is the format of the string always the same?

Comment: yes...its always same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "4 F= -0.15857709E+03 E0= -0.15857306E+03  d E =-0.612557E+01  mag=   111.0022"
>>> re.findall(r'[+-]?(?<!E)\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[+-]\d+)?)?', s)
['4', '-0.15857709E+03', '-0.15857306E+03', '-0.612557E+01', '111.0022']
```

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KOcT5aMKe1PvIRPS)

Comment: I was working on something like that...yea..fixing the `re` expression is what I would do instead of messing around with more `split` and `strip`...

Comment: That works because in `E0`, 0 is preceded by `E`, but I assume it's not always the case. For example it would fail for `s = "4 F= -0.15857709E+03 D0= -0.15857306E+03  d E =-0.612557E+01  mag=   111.0022"` because it returns an extra 0. You should probably use another negative assertion, such as `(?<!\w)`

Comment: @VincentSavard We can replace `E` with `[a-zA-Z]` if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex:

```
import re

s = '4 F= -0.15857709E+03 E0= -0.15857306E+03  d E =-0.612557E+01  mag=   111.0022'
qlist = [s.split()[0]] + [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'(?<==)\s*[^ ]+', s)]
print(qlist)
```

**Output**

```
['4', '-0.15857709E+03', '-0.15857306E+03', '-0.612557E+01', '111.0022']
```

The first number is extracted using `str.split()` for simplicity. The remainder of the numeric strings are then extracted using regex and stripped of whitespace at either end where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to try following regex.

```
 ([-]?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[+-]\d+)?)?)(?=(?:\s|$))
```

Sample code.

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([-]?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[+-]\d+)?)?)(?=(?:\s|$))')

test_str = "4 F= -0.15857709E+03 E0= -0.15857306E+03  d E =-0.612557E+01  mag=   111.0022"

matches = re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Given your sample input string and running demo, output will be

```
['4 ', '-0.15857709E+03 ', '-0.15857306E+03 ', '-0.612557E+01 ', '111.0022']
```

Please see demo at https://regex101.com/r/sO0aD8/3